# Power BI- Call Percentage of Total based in a Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Trust you are well!

I'm calculating % of total by adding a new measure by this formula:-

```
FY21 Q1 ACTUAL = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Page1'[Q1 FY21]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Page1'[Q1 FY21]),
        ALLSELECTED('Page1'[Domain])
    )
)
```

But when I'm applying filters to the "domain" then "FY21 Q1 ACTUAL" values are being changed. My goal is to keep the FY21 Q1 actual value as it is same even after applying "domain" level filter in another sheet/table. Currently it's giving % as "100%" when filter is applied by a particular domain name.

Please see the screengrab

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below **Measure**-

```
FY21 Q1 ACTUAL = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('Page1'[Q1 FY21]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Page1'[Q1 FY21]),
        ALL('Page1'[Domain])
    )
)
```

Comment: Wow, it's working now! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ashish1780 nice to see it worked and helped :)